# JavaFX SDK for NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I've NetBeans javafx project, in project>properties>libraries>JavaFX Platform there is "JavaFX SDK on Java 1.6 (Default)" but there is needed to create java 1.5 compatible applet. So I need something like "JavaFX SDK on Java 1.5" where I could get it?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX will only run on Java 6, so I think you might be out of luck if you your applet must run on Java 5.

Comment: Actually to solve this problem you have to install jdk 5 and install netbeans 6.8 on it, and there will be javaFx sdk on java 1.5 (the version of javafx will be 1.2)